# onResume sharedPrefs not loading anything

Tags: android, kotlin

I have the problem where my code correctly saved to `sharedPrefs` `onPause`, but gets nothing `onResume`.

I was following the sample code provided by [Google](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences)

Here is my code:

```
private val PREF_NAME = "type-data"

    override fun onPause() {

        val sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE) ?: return
        with(sharedPref.edit()) {
            putString("type1", type1)
            putString("type2", type2)
            apply()
//            commit()
        }
        Log.d("aaa", "paused. type1 is" + type1)

        super.onPause()
    }

    override fun onResume() {

        val sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE) ?: return
        type1 = sharedPref.getString("type1", "")
        type2 = sharedPref.getString("type2", "")

        Log.d("aaa", "resuming. type1 is" + type1)

        super.onResume()

        updateTypeText()
        updateTypesDisplay()
        updateModes()

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `getPreferences` with `getSharedPreferences`. If you copied code from Google's site you got a mismatch wanting to use `sharedPreferences`.

In `onResume`, replace:

```
val sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE) ?: return
```

with:

```
val sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE) ?: return
```